# How do you test a mouseover for desktop in webdriverio?

Tags: webdriver-io

It is possible to test a mobile tap event with:

`browser.element('.someSelector').touch(selector,longClick);`

There are other methods:

- performMultiAction
- performTouchAction
- touchClick
- touchDown
- touchFlick
- touchLongClick
- touchMove
- touchScroll
- touchUp

None of these work with desktop.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me using `moveToObject` and `pause`.

http://webdriver.io/api/action/moveToObject.html

http://webdriver.io/api/utility/pause.html

For example:

```
browser.moveToObject('#someElementSelector').pause(500).saveScreenshot();
```

Answer (score 2):

moveTo Command can be used for mouse hover. Please refer below link
https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/moveTo.html

Usage:

```
let btn = $('#myBtn');
btn.moveTo();
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use browser.execute with jquery mouse events.
    browser.execute($('selectors').mouseover());

Comment: It says Trigget is not a function.

Comment: This should work in most cases if the page that's being tested includes jQuery, but the command should be `browser.execute( () => { $( "selectors" ).mouseover(); } );`